# How render D3DFMT_A8 texture as colour?

Tags: graphics, directx, textures

Is it possible to render D3DFMT_A8 texture with some colour? Like this:

```
D3DXCreateTexture (pDevice, 128, 128, 0, D3DFMT_A8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &pTexture)
...
pSprite->Draw (pTexture, NULL, NULL , NULL, 0, pos, 0xffff0000);  // red
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting, that such a code doesn't work :(

Comment: It renders texture in grayscale palette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, not all hardware supports D3DFMT_A8.

Now assuming that ID3DXSprite doesn't take over too much of the pipeline then its a simple matter of writing a pixel shader as follows:

```
sampler2D input : register(s0); 
float4 pixelShader(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR 
{ 
    return tex2D( input , uv.xy).aaaa; 

}
```

The shader simply reads in the value in the texture and swizzles it across all channels.